# $\nabla div(B)=curl(E) \implies div(B)=0$ on non-convex domains

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I want to prove that a solution of the 2d problem
Find $$B \in H_0(div)=\{B \in [L^2(\Omega)]^2 | div B \in L^2(\Omega), B\cdot n=0 \ \ on\ \  \partial \Omega\}\\ 
E \in H^1_0(\Omega)\ \  s.t\   -\nabla div B + curl E=0$$

satisfies $\|div B\|_{L^2}=0$.

The weak form is to find $C \in H_0(div)$ s.t.

$(div B, div C)+ (curl E, C)=0$.   (1)

On convex domains we can consider the equation $(div \nabla \varphi=)\Delta \varphi = div B$. Since $div B$ is in $L²$ and $\Omega$ is convex we know that $\varphi \in H^2$. Then we can test (1) with $C=\nabla \varphi$ and get $(div B, div B) + (curl E, \nabla \varphi)=0$. The second term is zero since we can do integration by parts and $curl \nabla \varphi=0$. Here we have used that $\nabla \varphi$ has enough regularity to build the curl of it.

But what do we do on a non-convex domain? Then the result that $\varphi\in H^2(\Omega)$ doesn't hold anymore. One could say $\varphi \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\nabla \varphi \in H(div)$. But then we don't have enough regularity to perform integration by parts in the second term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi$ be the weak solution of 
$$
\Delta \phi = div \ B 
$$
subject to Neumann boundary conditions. That is
$$
\int \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla u =- \int div \ B \cdot u = \int B \cdot \nabla u
$$
for all $u\in H^1(\Omega)$. This proves that $div(\nabla \phi)=B$ in the weak sense and $\nabla \phi \cdot n =0$ in the weak sense. So $\nabla\phi \in H_0(div)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid you made a few typos in your answer, for example this expression $div(\nabla \phi)= B$ and $\phi \in H_0(div)$? What did you mean? And why does this imply $(curl E, \nabla \varphi)=0$?

Comment: I meant $\nabla \phi \in H_0(div)$, so it can be used even if $\phi$ does not belong to $H^2$

Comment: Okay, that in the nonconvex case still $\nabla \varphi \in H_0(div)$ I have already pointed out in the original post. My question is why $(curl E, \nabla \varphi)=0$ in this case?

Comment: Do you have an idea how to prove that?

Comment: One could approximate $\phi$ by smooth functions to prove this equation in a weak sense.